# Vagrant: Set Hostname Once on Vagrant Up

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, vagrantfile, vagrant-provision

I am attempting to use Vagrant and Chef-Client provisioning for a task I am working on. I want to be able to have a unique name generated when I use `vagrant up`, join the instance to the Chef Server, and then remove the node when completed. I have this mostly working; I am stuck on the automatic removal of the node from the Chef Server when I run Chef Destroy. I need to find a way to either cache off the name and retrieve it later, only run the hostname configuration at `vagrant up`, or some option that I have not figured out yet.

A snippet of my vagrantfile is as follows:

```
Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
  config.vm.box = 'centos/6'
  config.vm.hostname = "vagrant-#{SecureRandom.hex(2)}-el6.dev.local" 
  config.vm.provision 'chef_client' do |chef|
      chef.chef_server_url = 'https://chef.dev.local/organizations/foo'
      chef.add_role 'build_vm'
      chef.node_name = config.vm.hostname
      chef.delete_node = true
      chef.delete_client = true
  end
end
```

When this runs at `vagrant up` the hostname is set to `vagrant-229b-el6.dev.local` but at destruction it tries to destroy `vagrant-3a1c-el6.dev.local`. It is obviously running the `config.vm.hostname` line on each run, so the logical thing is to not let that happen. What do I need to do to have the hostname created by `vagrant up` persist so that Chef knows to remove it later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this with Vagrantfile only. I think, Vagrantfile is read on every vagrant run, so each time it generates another random name. What you can do though is to save the generated hostname into environment variable or file on first run and read it from there on next runs, and then remove file or unset the env variable on `vagrant destroy`.

This can be done by simple ruby code inside the Vagrantfile itself, like:

```
# We save the hostname into '.vagrant_hostname' file.
VAGRANT_HOSTNAME = '.vagrant_hostname'
if File.exist? VAGRANT_HOSTNAME
  hostname = IO.read( VAGRANT_HOSTNAME ).strip
else
  hostname = "vagrant-#{SecureRandom.hex(2)}-el6.dev.local"
  IO.write( VAGRANT_HOSTNAME, hostname )
end

Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
  [...]      
  config.vm.hostname = hostname
  [...]
end

if <the command is "vagrant destroy">
  File.delele VAGRANT_HOSTNAME
end
```

Comment: I think you could just rely on the `id` file generated by vagrant when it creates the VM and which is the virtualbox/vmware VM Id so you dont need to maintain another file.

Comment: I haven't worked with vagrant for a long time. If vagrant saves the hostname itself into some file, using that file definitely would be an cleaner solution.

Comment: well, need to detail - no it does not save the hostname itself, but vagrant maintains a file with the id of the VM it creates (part of the files under the `.vagrant` folder) so I would see that the OP is not running the line `config.vm.hostname = "vagrant-#{SecureRandom.hex(2)}-el6.dev.local"` if this file exists which means the VM has already been setup and the hostname has been set

Comment: Thank you all - I created a combined solution with the various inputs. In the end, I created a `.vagrant_hostname` file under the `.vagrant` folder and wrote the hostname to that. Relying on the `id` file would have worked too but I wanted to be able to get the hostname for other purposes. 

I couldn't figure out the `if <the command is "vagrant destroy">` line in Ruby, but the combined behavior of checking for the existence of the file and the fact that the .vagrant folder gets obliterated on destroy gets me where I need to go. 

Thus I shall accept this answer.